# What are the differences between Labyrinth Lord and B/X D&D (Moldvay)?

Tags: edition-comparison, osr, dnd-bx, labyrinth-lord

Aside from small things like layout, art, and the exact wording of rules, what are the major differences between the D&D retro-clone *Labyrinth Lord* and its primary inspiration, the 1981 D&D Basic/Expert (B/X) by Tom Moldvay?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this blog](https://leyline.press/blogs/leyline-press-blog/a-comparative-exploration-of-osr-rpg-systems-labyrinth-lord): -

> it adds elements from BECMI, and AD&D

and

> The changes it does have [from Moldvay Basic] are relatively minor throughout.

It goes on to outline some of the differences - for example that

> The Cleric gains a spell at first level in Labyrinth Lord whereas in B/X  and BECMI they did not

and more generally compares the different editions, and how they have been adjusted, combined, or retained.